# Android app closes automatically in mobile

Tags: android-studio

I have developed an app but when I try to open it on my mobile, it closes immediately, any helps?

Comment: code snippet or further explanation is required to answer this. check your error log.

Comment: Hello @Filippo, welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be great if you could add the exact error that you are getting if any. Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)